# STL count algorithm returning incorrect value.

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I have to find the major element of the sequence :

```
92,19,19,76,19,21,19,85,19,19,19,94,19,19,22,67,83,19,19,54,59,1,19,19
```

A major element is the one which appears more that size/2 times in the collection.

now the problem is that after counting 92 it will remove all the elements from the collection with value 92 and after that it will count the number of 19s.The number of 19′s in this sequence is 13 but the count algorithm is just returning 1.
The count algorithm is returning the proper answer for just the first element of the sequence.

Here’s the function:

```
int countMajor(vector<int>& v)
{
  int max = (v.size() / 2);
  int c = 0;
  do{
    c = count(v.begin(), v.end(), v[0]);
    if (c > max)
      return v[0];
    v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&v](int i){
      if (v[0] == i)
        return true;
      return false;
    }), v.end());
  } while (!v.empty());
  return -1;
}
```

After counting 92 it will be removed and `v[1]` i.e 19 will be the new `v[0]`.
I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: counting looks okay but the erase looks pretty suspect.

Comment: Why do you use `remove_if`. Plain `remove` would suffice (`std::remove` has two overloads with completely different meanings, but the 3-argument form is for what you need).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The `erase` is exactly as required. See [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @RakibulHasan: Return value of the closure is `bool`. Return value of the function `countMajor` is `int`, but I don't see that return boolean anywhere!

Comment: @JanHudec, You are right. Missed the upper line.

Comment: @JanHudec: no, while the `erase` may be OK, the erase is not. see the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23424422/464581).

Comment: @JanHudec :yeah you are right it does work with remove but I was learning about lambda expressions so I used it in this question. :)

Comment: @user3595595: And accidentally introduced the bug in the process. If you used plain `remove`, it would take the element to delete by value and wouldn't cause the problem.

Comment: @user3595595 - As to the wording of your topic, algorithms always return the correct value.  What is *not* correct is your usage of them.  If an STL algorithm truly did not return the correct results, then it's time to contact the creator of the STL implementation for your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are erasing v[0].

Make it:

```
int e = v[0];
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [e](int i){
  if (e == i)
    return true;
  return false;
}), v.end());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Its working now.Cheers! But how is it different that removing v[0] because e is also v[0],right?

Comment: @Dieter: why are you capturing `v`. and even by reference.

Comment: I just fixed it. not doing anything about the `if` statement, since that's not technically dangerous (just bad style). to fix also that statement, just do `return (e == i);`.

Comment: @user3595595: Because when the `erase` removes `v[0]` in the first step, it will move another element in it's place. And from then on, you are comparing with something else than you wanted.

Comment: oh, while we're at it, the OP's `remove_if` is a bit of overkill here, as already remarked by others.